# Calculations across dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, lapply

I have two lists of dataframes, the first list of dfs hold values that extend down the column and the second list of dfs holds single values like this:

```
dynamic_df_1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
dynamic_df_2 <- data.frame(y = 1:10)
df_list <- list(dynamic_df_1, dynamic_df_2)
df_list

static_df_1 <- data.frame(mu = 10,
                          stdev = 5)
static_df_2 <- data.frame(mu = 12,
                          stdev = 6)
static_df_list <- list(stat_df1 = static_df_1, 
                       stat_df2 = static_df_2)
static_df_list
```

I would like to add a column to each dataframe (dynamic_df_1 and dynamic_df_2) using values from static_df_1 and static_df_2 to perform the calculation where the calculation for dynamic_df_1 computes with static_df_1 and the calculation for dynamic_df_2 computes with static_df_2.

The result I'm aiming for is this:

```
df_list[[1]] <- df_list[[1]] %>%
  mutate(z = dnorm(x = df_list[[1]]$x, mean = static_df_list$stat_df1$mu, sd = static_df_list$stat_df1$stdev))
df_list

df_list[[2]] <- df_list[[2]] %>%
  mutate(z = dnorm(x = df_list[[2]]$y, mean = static_df_list$stat_df2$mu, sd = static_df_list$stat_df2$stdev))
df_list
```

I can take a loop approach which gets messy with more complex functions in my real code:

```
for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
    df_list[[i]]$z <- dnorm(x = df_list[[i]][[1]], mean = static_df_list[[i]]$mu, sd = static_df_list[[i]]$stdev)
}
df_list
```

I'm trying to find an lapply / map / mutate type solution that calculates across dataframes - imagine a grid of dataframes where the objective is to calculate across rows. Also open to other solutions such as single df with nested values but haven't figured out how to do that yet.

Hope that is clear - I did my best!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `Map` solution seems to be simpler. And the results are `identical()`. The code that creates `df_list2` and `df_list3` follows below.

```
df_list4 <- df_list

fun <- function(DF, Static_DF){
  DF[["z"]] = dnorm(DF[[1]], mean = Static_DF[["mu"]], sd = Static_DF[["stdev"]])
  DF
}

df_list4 <- Map(fun, df_list4, static_df_list)


identical(df_list2, df_list3)
#[1] TRUE

identical(df_list2, df_list4)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Data.**

After running the question's code that creates the initial `df_list`, run the `dplyr` pipe and `for` loop code:

```
df_list2 <- df_list

df_list2[[1]] <- df_list2[[1]] %>%
  mutate(z = dnorm(x = df_list2[[1]]$x, mean = static_df_list$stat_df1$mu, sd = static_df_list$stat_df1$stdev))

df_list2[[2]] <- df_list2[[2]] %>%
  mutate(z = dnorm(x = df_list2[[2]]$y, mean = static_df_list$stat_df2$mu, sd = static_df_list$stat_df2$stdev))


df_list3 <- df_list

for (i in 1:length(df_list3)) {
  df_list3[[i]]$z <- dnorm(x = df_list3[[i]][[1]], mean = static_df_list[[i]]$mu, sd = static_df_list[[i]]$stdev)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that is an elegant solution with the function @Rui Barradas :).
Out of curiosity I checked out the microbenchmark - for anyone interested:

`microbenchmark(Map(fun, df_list4, static_df_list),
               for (i in 1:length(df_list3)) {
                 df_list3[[i]]$z <- dnorm(x = df_list3[[i]][[1]], mean = static_df_list[[i]]$mu, sd = static_df_list[[i]]$stdev)
               })`

Comment: `# Unit: microseconds
# expr          min                lq            mean     median           uq          max    neval
# Map     41.201       46.7005     71.32204      65.501    81.951     198.601     100
# loop  3583.002 4053.2015  4801.83906  4333.851 5067.651  12399.501    100`

Might make a noteworthy difference when run on a large scale. Apologies about the formatting...